# Why does rsync fail to copy files from /sys in Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rsync, sysfs

I have a bash script which uses `rsync` to backup files in Archlinux. I noticed that `rsync` failed to copy a file from `/sys`, while `cp` worked just fine:

```
# rsync /sys/class/net/enp3s1/address /tmp    
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/class/net/enp3s1/address": No data available (61)
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/class/net/enp3s1/address": No data available (61)
ERROR: address failed verification -- update discarded.
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]

# cp  /sys/class/net/enp3s1/address /tmp   ## this works
```

I wonder why does `rsync` fail, and is it possible to copy the file with it?

Comment: Why do you want to copy `/sys/`?

Comment: @frostschutz I use the command in the OP to copy the MAC-address of a network card (as a file)

Comment: @eugeney So, why isn't it sufficient to backup the config file where the MAC address is set from?

Comment: @eugeney Is it even possible to write to `/sys/class/net/*/address` (I get "permission denied" when I try it)?  If not, then you aren't making a real/useful backup since it can't be restored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rsync has [code](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=fileio.c;h=0e207141eee5c7b868d8b57c2b06b216bd9232d4;hb=HEAD) which specifically checks if a file is truncated during read and gives this error — `ENODATA`. I don't know *why* the files in `/sys` have this behavior, but since they're not real files, I guess it's not too surprising. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell rsync to skip this particular check.

I think you're probably better off not rsyncing `/sys` and using specific scripts to cherry-pick out the particular information you want (like the network card address).

Comment: Pfft, where's the fun in not figuring out why rsync in particular fails?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Rsync specifically checks for files truncated during read and throws this error.

Comment: I'd presume they have this behaviour because until you actually read them, what's "there" is not absolutely certain; the read is really a request for dynamic information from the kernel.  So the kernel does not try to give accurate details WRT to the file size, etc, in advance, and as you point out, rsync takes such a discrepancy as a bad sign.

Answer (score 14):

First off `/sys` is a *pseudo file system*. If you look at `/proc/filesystems` you will find a list of registered file systems where quite a few has `nodev`
in front. This indicates they are *pseudo filesystems*. This means they exists
on a running kernel as a RAM-based filesystem. Further they do not require a
block device.

```
$ cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
...
```

At boot the kernel mount this system and updates entries when suited. E.g. when
new hardware is found during boot or by `udev`.

In `/etc/mtab` you typically find the mount by:

```
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

For a nice paper on the subject read 
[Patric Mochel's – The sysfs Filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf).

---

## stat of /sys files

If you go into a directory under `/sys` and do a `ls -l` you will notice that
all files has one size. Typically 4096 bytes. This is reported by `sysfs`.

```
:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth2$ ls -l
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 20:09 addr_assign_type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 20:09 address
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 20:09 addr_len
...
```

Further you can do a `stat` on a file and notice another distinct feature;
it occupies 0 blocks. Also inode of root (stat /sys) is 1. `/stat/fs` typically
has inode 2. etc.

## rsync vs. cp

The easiest explanation for rsync failure of synchronizing pseudo files is
perhaps by example.

Say we have a file named `address` that is 18 bytes. An `ls` or `stat` of the
file reports 4096 bytes.

---

### rsync

1. Opens file descriptor, fd.
2. Uses fstat(fd) to get information such as size.
3. Set out to read size bytes, i.e. 4096. That would be [line 253](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=fileio.c;h=0e207141eee5c7b868d8b57c2b06b216bd9232d4;hb=HEAD#l253) of the code linked by [@mattdm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2511/mattdm). `read_size == 4096`

   1. Ask; read: 4096 bytes.
   2. A short string is read i.e. 18 bytes. `nread == 18`
   3. `read_size = read_size - nread (4096 - 18 = 4078)`
   4. Ask; read: 4078 bytes
   5. 0 bytes read (as first read consumed all bytes in file).
   6. `nread == 0` , [line 255](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=fileio.c;h=0e207141eee5c7b868d8b57c2b06b216bd9232d4;hb=HEAD#l255)
   7. Unable to read `4096` bytes. Zero out buffer.
   8. Set error `ENODATA`.
   9. Return.
4. Report error.
5. Retry. (Above loop).
6. Fail.
7. Report error.
8. FINE.

During this process it actually reads the entire file. But with no size
available it cannot validate the result – thus failure is only option.

### cp

1. Opens file descriptor, fd.
2. Uses fstat(fd) to get information such as st_size (also uses lstat and stat).
3. Check if file is likely to be sparse. That is the file has holes etc.

   ```
   copy.c:1010
   /* Use a heuristic to determine whether SRC_NAME contains any sparse
    * blocks.  If the file has fewer blocks than would normally be
    * needed for a file of its size, then at least one of the blocks in
    * the file is a hole.  */
   sparse_src = is_probably_sparse (&src_open_sb);
   ```

   As `stat` reports file to have zero blocks it is categorized as sparse.
4. Tries to read file by extent-copy (a more efficient way to copy *normal*
   sparse files), and fails.
5. Copy by sparse-copy.

   1. Starts out with max read size of MAXINT. 
      Typically
      `18446744073709551615` bytes on a 32 bit system.
   2. Ask; read 4096 bytes. (Buffer size allocated in memory from stat information.)
   3. A short string is read i.e. 18 bytes.
   4. Check if a hole is needed, nope.
   5. Write buffer to target.
   6. Subtract 18 from max read size.
   7. Ask; read 4096 bytes.
   8. 0 bytes as all got consumed in first read.
   9. Return success.
6. All OK. Update flags for file.
7. FINE.

Answer (score 3):

Might be related, but extended attribute calls will fail on sysfs:

> [root@hypervisor eth0]# lsattr address
>
> lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on address
>
> [root@hypervisor eth0]#

Looking at my strace it looks like rsync tries to pull in extended attributes by default:

> 22964 <... getxattr resumed> , 0x7fff42845110, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)

I tried finding a flag to give rsync to see if skipping extended attributes resolves the issue but wasn't able to find anything (`--xattrs` turns them *on* at the destination).

Answer (score 0):

Rsync normally read the file's information, transfer file contents or delta's to a temporary file in the destination directory, then after verifying the file's data it renames it to the destination filename.

I believe the problem with sysfs is that all files shows as 4k (one memory page) yet they may contain only a few bytes. To avoid copying a potentially corrupt file to the destination rsync cancels the copy when it sees a mismatch between the file's metadata and what was actually copied.

At least on rsync v3.0.6 this behaviour can be avoided using the `--inplace` switch. Rsync will still detect errors but since the destination files will already have been overwriten when it does it will leave the potentially corrupt files there.

Note though that a side effect of it is that files end up being zero-padded to 4k as this is the size rsync thinks the files are. It shouldn't make a difference in most cases as null bytes are usually ignored.