# Why does cp --no-preserve=mode preserves the mode? Alternative tools available?

Tags: permissions, symlink, cp, file-copy

```
$ cp --no-preserve=mode --parents /sys/power/state /tmp/test/
$ cp --no-preserve=mode --parents /sys/bus/cpu/drivers_autoprobe /tmp/test/
```

The second of the two lines will fail with

```
cp: cannot make directory ‘/tmp/test/sys/bus’: Permission denied
```

And the reason is that `/tmp/test/sys` is created without write permission (as is the original `/sys`); a normal `mkdir /tmp/test/sys2` would not have done this:

```
$ ls -la /tmp/test/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  3 robert.siemer domain^users  4096 Oct 11 13:56 .
drwxrwxrwt 13 root          root         20480 Oct 11 13:56 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  3 robert.siemer domain^users  4096 Oct 11 13:56 sys
drwxr-xr-x  2 robert.siemer domain^users  4096 Oct 11 13:59 sys2
```

How can I instruct `cp` to not preserve the mode, apart from `--no-preserve=mode`, which does not work as I believe it should...?

Or which tool should I use to copy a list of files without preserving “anything” except symlinks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case you are using GNU coreutils. This is a bug which is fixed in version 8.26.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2016-08/msg00016.html

So the alternative tool would be an **up-to-date coreutils**, or for example `rsync` which is able to do that even with preserving permissions:

```
$ rsync -a --relative  /sys/power/state /tmp/test
$ rsync -a --relative  /sys/bus/cpu/drivers_autoprobe /tmp/test/
```

Though I see rsync has other problems for this particular sysfs files, see
[rsync option to disable verification?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315680/rsync-option-to-disable-verification)

Another harsh workaround would be to `chmod` all the dirs after each `cp` command.

```
$ find /tmp/test -type d -exec chmod $(umask -S) {} \;
```

(The find/chmod command above would also not work for *any* combination of existing permissions and umask.)

**BTW** you could report this bug to your Linux-Distribution and they might fix your 8.21 package via maintenance updates.

Comment: Yes, I’m using GNU coreutils version 8.21...

Comment: Rsync in sysfs fails: [Why does rsync fail to copy files from /sys in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73569/9417)

Answer (score -1):

A simple workaround for the bug

```
#!/bin/sh

for last; do : ; done

while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
  mkdir -p "${last}/$(dirname "$1")"
  cp --parents "$1" "$last"
  shift
done
```